# What does using or not using RASA core imply?

Tags: rasa-core

In context of my bachelor thesis it is my task to create a chatbot that will act as  some kind of helpdesk. This means the chatbot will have to be able to interact with some external layers of code/API's. I hope this is enough context to answer my question.

Until now I've pretty much been working on the NLU component of my chatbot, which is now working pretty fine already. I'm ready for the next step which would be connecting this NLU to the next layer in the system that will further the process the intent and entities, do some auxillary stuff, and formulate a response base on what the original intent/entities were and what it got back from doing the auxillary stuff (which will be interacting with the API).

I've read up on RASA Core and I know what it does. It'll train a model given some example conversations and use that model to guess which actions it should perform or which response it should give based on the intent/entities it receives. To me this seems like something I would like to use, however my professor advised against this but he's not entirly sure. His opinion is that RASA core doesn't give us enough freedom to make the chatbot interact with those additional software layers/API's. This is where my questions come in:

- Does using RASA Core make it more difficult to interact with other software layers/API's?
- Is RASA Core essential to creating a chatbot or can you in a realistic fashion create one without using RASA Core (or another similar framework)? Especially since RASA Core seems to offer a lot of functionallity, mainly the fact it provides you with a framework that will make the chatbot know what to do and when. It seems difficult to do this by myself.
- If I decide to not use it, what is best starting point to continue my project?

Since this is my first question on this forum I hope I didn't make my questions too long or confusion, if so let me know!

Hopefully someone will be able to shine some light on this situation.

Answer (score 1):

> Does using RASA Core make it more difficult to interact with other software layers/API's?

No. Rasa Core also follows an "API first" approach, which means everything should be accessible through the [API](https://legacy-docs.rasa.com/docs/core/server/#).

> Is RASA Core essential to creating a chatbot

If you are building a FAQ bot (question-answer pairs) then you might not need Core. But if actually want to build a bot which understands some context, and acts differently based on the history of the conversation, then you should use Rasa Core. Also, Rasa Core includes support for several [channels](https://legacy-docs.rasa.com/docs/core/connectors/) (Slack, Socket.io, Telegram, ...) out of the box, which should make it even easier to hook up your bot which different endpoints.

> If I decide to not use it, what is best starting point to continue my project?

Probably the [HTTP API of Rasa NLU](https://legacy-docs.rasa.com/docs/nlu/http/), so that you can integrate the queries in your application. The Rasa blog also contains a lot of blog posts about NLU, e.g. the Rasa NLU in Depth series which might help you to understand the Rasa NLU better ([link to part 1](https://blog.rasa.com/rasa-nlu-in-depth-part-1-intent-classification/) of the series).